# Print only the lines that with all digits except the last one or the last two characters or the first or second characters

Tags: sed, command-line

I have a big text file has lines with all numbers and with all letters and characters and also has lines mixed with numbers , letters and characters i want to print only the lines that have all numbers except the last or the last two characters.

1. Print the line that start with number but ends with any character at the last or the last two characters that is not a digit.
   For example

   ```
   1234567a
   2245678902da
   A1234566d
   12345678abc
   ```

   The output have to be

   ```
   1234567a
   22345678902da
   ```
2. Print the lines that have all their characters are digits except the first or the first and second characters to be not a digit.
   For example

   ```
   A1234
   Ab1234
   1a1234
   Abc1234
   ```

   The output have to be

   ```
   A1234
   Ab1234
   ```

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

```
$ grep -Ex '[[:digit:]]+(.|[^[:digit:]]{2})' file1
1234567a
2245678902da
```

The extended regular expression `[[:digit:]]+(.|[^[:digit:]]{2})` will match one or more digits followed by either an unspecified character or two non-digits (this is a literal interpretation of your specification "start with number but *ends with any character at the last or the last two characters that is not a digit*").  The `-x` option to `grep` ensures that the match will be across full lines.

Note that this literal interpretation of what you specified also matches lines that contain *only* digits.

With

```
$ grep -Ex '[^[:digit:]]{1,2}[[:digit:]]+' file2
A1234
Ab1234
```

we match lines that start with one or two non-digits, and then contains one or more digits until the end of the line.

---

For a visual representation of the two regular expressions (and also at the same time showing how to do it with `sed`):

The first:

```
$ sed -nE 's/^([[:digit:]]+)(.|[^[:digit:]]{2})$/(\1)(\2)/p' file1
(234567)(a)
(2245678902)(da)
```

The second:

```
$ sed -nE 's/^([^[:digit:]]{1,2})([[:digit:]]+)$/(\1)(\2)/p' file2
(A)(1234)
(Ab)(1234)
```

Remove all parentheses from the `sed` command to get the `sed` solution.

Answer (score 0):

Slightly different interpretation. I read this as the last 1-2 characters cannot be digits so I get

```
grep -E '^[[:digit:]]+[^[:digit:]]{1,2}$' file
1234567a
2245678902da
```

Comment: Hello all How to except the first character or or the first and second characters from being digits to print these lines ?

Comment: @Crun: lease don't expand your question in a comment; edit the question. And, why not try to apply the lessons learned in here to provide your own solution?

Comment: @Kusalananda your answer is not right cos it prints the line if it has for example 12345c3 but the answer required to be the last or the last two characters not to be digits

Comment: @Crun When I answered, your question specified that the last two characters were allowed to be anything. I interpreted "anything" as _anything_, including digits. I see that you have updated the question and will update my answer in a while.  Also, comments on my answer should go beneath my answer.

Comment: @Doug O’Neal your answer is ok .. thanks. Could you please answer the item #2 in my my question above?

Comment: @Crun First, you have edited your question so that my answer no long applies. Please as a new question instead of substantially changing you original question. Second,I agree with RudiC that you should try your own solution now that you've seen a solution to a similar problem. Finally, I defer to Kuslananda's solution now that the question is less ambiguous.

Answer (score 0):

For first question  below is command

```
sed -n '/^[0-9]*[a-z]\{,2\}$/p' filename
```

output

```
1234567a
2245678902da
```

For second question below is the command

```
 sed -n '/^[A-Za-z]\{1,2\}[0-9]*$/p'
```

output:

```
A1234
Ab1234
```